# How to update autoconf if I don't have root privilege?

Tags: linux, gnu, build, autoconf, autotools

Failed to run `autoreconf -iv`, for i am using a old autoconf, but i can not update it using system package manager since i am not root

so how to update autoconf from 2.59 to 2.64?

error message when run autoreconf:

```
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ autoreconf -iv
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal
configure.ac:33: error: Please use exactly Autoconf 2.64 instead of 2.59.
config/override.m4:104: _GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:33: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.59
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install autoconf in your home directory.  Get a copy of the autoconf tarball, unpack it, cd into the resulting directory and run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

You will probably want to also install newer versions of automake and libtool.  Then make sure your path is setup so that `autoreconf` runs from $HOME/bin.